# Spotify not starting since updating to 15.04

Tags: 15.04, spotify

Since updating to to 15.04 my spotify will not open. Any thoughts?
I have tried the lib 11 solution but that has not worked

Comment: I found I had to reinstall Spotify by editing Software Sources; the Spotify repository had been disabled at the time of upgrade.

Comment: I tried to reinstall but with the same result

Comment: What result exactly? What was the error message?

Answer (score 17):

This is caused by  `libgcrypt` . You can solve this by:

```
wget http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/libg/libgcrypt11/libgcrypt11_1.5.0-5+deb7u3_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i libgcrypt11_1.5.0-5+deb7u3_amd64.deb
```

If this doesn't work then purge `spotify` and install again from this repository.

```
sudo apt-get purge spotify*
```

Then

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free"
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 94558F59
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install spotify-client
```

Comment: The first part of this answer worked for me on 15.10 as well