# Spotify does not launch (starts) on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, spotify

I just got ubuntu and i tried to get spotify for it
I found this
https://www.spotify.com/ec/download/linux/
I did that exact thing... the program appeared in my system. everything was alright. Now when I click on it, it appears that it tries to get in the program 
but it never does... I click on the icon and nothing pops up
Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a common error, look here
[Spotify not starting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614713/spotify-not-starting-since-updating-to-15-04)